# Build page base on category

Tags: categories

I know how to hardcode that... but i like to have a plugin with shortcode that will make it for me... do you know any...

If not, i will have to make it myself

Have a page (blank) and build it base on post category. So in page xyz display all the post with category=abc. So the build page will display all the abc post back to back.

Framework do that, but i only have a simple theme... how to do that ?

And yes, i know that clicking on category will just do that, but it's less managable !

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to say. Could you post a link to your page, illustrate what exactly is your problem? And what do you mean with "i know that clicking on category will just do that, but it's less managable !"?

Comment: Auto listing the category dont allow to add picture and text to the top to explain what will fallow

Comment: making the right research append to get me the right OUTPUT and answer... will try this one : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-shortcode-w-generator/

Comment: I still don't get it, but glad you found a solution.

Comment: @menardman: It's good that you found the solution yourself. You can add it as an answer and accept if (after two days), to indicate that this question is no longer unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont quite understand how it's less easier to manage a category...

So you have `Category -> Post` but instead you want `Page -> Category -> Post`

It doesn't make sense in what you are trying to do.

And and if your trying to link categories into pages just so you can include them in some form of navigation, WP3.0+ has the ability to link categories with `Appearance -> Menus`.

And you don't really manage a category you just manage the posts associated to a category.